# Is it possible to calculate the average of differents values of several lines and generate the result on one line of a new sheet on Excel?

Tags: excel, vba, average

I have a dataframe with several values of volume, concentration and sugar quantity (around 5 values) per species and I would like to create a new sheet with only one line per species with the name of the species, and the average volume, the average concentration and the average sugar quantity for the species.

Source sheet :

| Spe | Vol | C | Qty sugar |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 |  |  |  |
| 1 |  |  |  |
| 1 |  |  |  |
| 2 |  |  |  |
| 2 |  |  |  |

What I want on the second sheet:

| Spe | mean(Vol) | mean(C) | mean(Qty sugar) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 |  |  |  |
| 2 |  |  |  |

I tried to code a Macro VBA on excel but I'm not used to it, I thought it was going to generate automatically a table with all the average value for each species but it didn't work.

Is there a simple way to do this ?

Comment: Try an Excel pivot table. No VBA needed.

Answer (score 1):

There are different ways to do this: you can use the Excel's "Subtotals" feature, choosing "Average" as a subtotal's function:

[image]

However, here you have the drawback that you have the results on the same page, those results look like this (after having clicked on <kbd>2</kbd> in the left margin):

[image]

In order to have the results on another page, you might use the `=Subtotals()` function, but maybe you might go for a pivot table, as already suggested by [Bugdrown](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1277402/bugdrown), this is how it should look like:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

### Get Column Averages of Matching Rows

[image]

**VBA**

```vb
Sub PopulateAverages()
    
    ' Define constants.
    
    Const SRC_SHEET As String = "Sheet1"
    Const DST_SHEET As String = "Sheet2"
    Const DST_FIRST_CELL As String = "A2"
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    ' Write the source values to an array.
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Sheets(SRC_SHEET)
    
    Dim srg As Range, srCount As Long, cCount As Long
    
    With sws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
        srCount = .Rows.Count - 1
        If srCount = 0 Then Exit Sub ' no data rows
        cCount = .Columns.Count
        If cCount < 2 Then Exit Sub ' no value columns
        Set srg = .Resize(srCount).Offset(1)
    End With
    
    Dim sData(): sData = srg.Value
    
    ' Write the unique values from the first column to the 'keys'
    ' of a dictionary and each row index to the collection held
    ' by the associated 'items'.
    
    Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
    
    Dim sKey, sr As Long
    
    For sr = 1 To srCount
        sKey = sData(sr, 1)
        If Not IsError(sKey) Then
            If Len(CStr(sKey)) > 0 Then
                If Not dict.Exists(sKey) Then
                    Set dict(sKey) = New Collection
                End If
                dict(sKey).Add sr
            End If
        End If
    Next sr
    
    If dict.Count = 0 Then Exit Sub ' only blanks and/or error values
    
    ' Write the averages to another array.
    
    Dim dData(): ReDim dData(1 To dict.Count, 1 To cCount)
    
    Dim sItem, sValue, dr As Long, c As Long, tCount As Long, Total As Double
    
    For Each sKey In dict.Keys
        dr = dr + 1
        dData(dr, 1) = sKey
        tCount = dict(sKey).Count
        For c = 2 To cCount
            For Each sItem In dict(sKey)
                sValue = sData(sItem, c)
                If VarType(sValue) = vbDouble Then
                    Total = Total + sValue
                End If
            Next sItem
            dData(dr, c) = Total / tCount ' maybe do some rounding here
            Total = 0 ' reset for the next iteration (column)
        Next c
    Next sKey

    ' Write the values from the array to the destination range.

    ' Reference the destination range.
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Sheets(DST_SHEET)
    Dim dfCell As Range: Set dfCell = dws.Range(DST_FIRST_CELL)
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = dfCell.Resize(dr, cCount)
    ' Write the result.
    drg.Value = dData
    ' Clear below.
    drg.Resize(dws.Rows.Count - drg.Row - dr + 1).Offset(dr).Clear
    
    ' Inform.
    
    MsgBox "Averages populated.", vbInformation

End Sub
```

**Excel Formula (Microsoft 365)**

```
=LET(data,Sheet1!A2:D6,
    ud,TAKE(data,,1),vd,DROP(data,,1),
    u,TOCOL(UNIQUE(ud),3),
    rd,REDUCE("",u,LAMBDA(rr,r,LET(
            f,FILTER(vd,ud=r),
            bc,BYCOL(f,LAMBDA(c,
                AVERAGE(c))),
        VSTACK(rr,bc)))),
HSTACK(u,DROP(rd,1)))
```

Answer (score 0):

try

assuming Spe-Vol-C-Qte in column A-B-C-D

```
Sub CalculateAverages()
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim dict As Object
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim value As Variant
    Dim sumVol As Double, sumC As Double, sumQTE As Double
    Dim countVol As Long, countC As Long, countQTE As Long
    Dim currentRow As Long
    
    Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") ' Replace "Sheet1" with your sheet name
    Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2") ' Replace "Sheet2" with your sheet name
    

    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    lastRow = ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    
        ' Add unique values to the dictionary
    For Each cell In ws1.Range("A2:A" & lastRow)
        If Not dict.Exists(CStr(cell)) Then
            dict(CStr(cell)) = True
        End If
    Next cell
    
    ' Set initial row in Sheet2
    currentRow = 2
    
    ' Loop through each unique value in the dictionary
    For Each value In dict.Keys
        
        sumVol = 0
        sumC = 0
        sumQTE = 0
        countVol = 0
        countC = 0
        countQTE = 0

        For Each cell In ws1.Range("A2:A" & lastRow)
            If CStr(cell.value) = value Then
                sumVol = sumVol + cell.Offset(0, 1).value
                sumC = sumC + cell.Offset(0, 2).value
                sumQTE = sumQTE + cell.Offset(0, 3).value
                countVol = countVol + 1
                countC = countC + 1
                countQTE = countQTE + 1
            End If
        Next cell
        
        ' Write results to Sheet2
        ws2.Cells(currentRow, "A").value = value
        ws2.Cells(currentRow, "B").value = sumVol / countVol
        ws2.Cells(currentRow, "C").value = sumC / countC
        ws2.Cells(currentRow, "D").value = sumQTE / countQTE
        
        ' Move to the next row in Sheet2
        currentRow = currentRow + 1
    Next value
End Sub
```